# Parse Cloud : Module already being loaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I am trying to use crypto module of nodejs and added all required modules into my cloud folder and changed all require('..') methods as require('cloud/..) but getting error while deploying to cloud :

Update failed with Could not load triggers. The error was Error: Module cloud/stream.js is already being loaded

at _stream_readable.js:26:14
at stream.js:28:19
at crypto.js:40:14
at main.js:3:14
Because stream_readable.js requires stream.js and there is a circular dependency between stream.js and stream_readable.js.

Is there any solution or workaround for this circular dependencies?

Comment: If `cloud` is relative to the script's directory, did you try `require('./cloud/..);` ?

Comment: Referenced js files located succesfully, there is no path issue.

Answer (score 0):

As show in the Documentation
https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#modules

you need to use exports when using your own modules

```
var coolNames = ['Ralph', 'Skippy', 'Chip', 'Ned', 'Scooter'];
exports.isACoolName = function(name) {
  return coolNames.indexOf(name) !== -1;
}

var name = require('cloud/name.js');
name.isACoolName('Fred'); // returns false
name.isACoolName('Skippy'); // returns true;
name.coolNames; // undefined.
```

Comment: That is not the case, there is no accessibility issue.

Comment: From Docs "In order to avoid unwanted side effects from loading modules, Cloud Code's modules work similarly to CommonJS modules." So try wrapping stream.js in a exports variable then wrap the stream.js used in stream_readable in another exports variable

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for a couple weeks as well.  Turns out NodeJS isn't the best option (yet, anyways) for Parse Cloud Code signature signing/verification but I did find a solution.

According to Chris Stewart's response [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-crypto-module), you can use the jsrsasign library instead.

Here's some cloud code of a working example:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("verifySignature", function(request, response) {
    var KJUR = require('cloud/jsrsasign/npm/lib/jsrsasign.js');
    var strPubKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----(snip)';

    // initialize
    var pubKey = KJUR.KEYUTIL.getKey(strPubKey);
    var data = request.params.data;
    var signature = request.params.signature;
    var verifier = new KJUR.Signature({"alg": "SHA1withRSA", "prov": "cryptojs/jsrsa"});

    // initialize for signature validation
    verifier.initVerifyByPublicKey(pubKey);

    // update data
    verifier.updateString(data);

    // verify signature
    if (verifier.verify(base64ToHex(signature))
        response.success("Signature verified");
    else
        response.error("Signature could not be verified"); 
}

function base64ToHex(str) {
  for (var i = 0, bin = atob(str.replace(/[ \r\n]+$/, "")), hex = []; i < bin.length; ++i) {
    var tmp = bin.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
    if (tmp.length === 1) tmp = "0" + tmp;
    hex[hex.length] = tmp;
  }
  return hex.join(" ");
}

function atob(base64) {
  var tableStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
  var table = tableStr.split("");

  if (/(=[^=]+|={3,})$/.test(base64)) throw new Error("String contains an invalid character");
  base64 = base64.replace(/=/g, "");
  var n = base64.length & 3;
  if (n === 1) throw new Error("String contains an invalid character");
  for (var i = 0, j = 0, len = base64.length / 4, bin = []; i < len; ++i) {
    var a = tableStr.indexOf(base64[j++] || "A"), b = tableStr.indexOf(base64[j++] || "A");
    var c = tableStr.indexOf(base64[j++] || "A"), d = tableStr.indexOf(base64[j++] || "A");
    if ((a | b | c | d) < 0) throw new Error("String contains an invalid character");
    bin[bin.length] = ((a << 2) | (b >> 4)) & 255;
    bin[bin.length] = ((b << 4) | (c >> 2)) & 255;
    bin[bin.length] = ((c << 6) | d) & 255;
  };
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, bin).substr(0, bin.length + n - 4);
}
```